# Split File Fullname path

Tags: powershell

I wondering if this is possible, I tried to use "split-Path" wrongly and my filename dissappears. Thanks in advance.

Actual Output:

```
\\myHostname\c$\users\myUser\desktop -- 9,05 MB

Ficheros                                                                 Megas
--------                                                                 -----
\\myHostname\c$\users\myUser\Desktop\something.exe                       5,00
\\myHostname\c$\users\myUser\Desktop\photo.jpg                           2,00
```

desired output:

```
Ficheros                           Megas
--------                           ------
\Desktop\something.exe             5,00
\Desktop\photo.jpg                 2,00
```

CODE:

```
param([string]$pc,[string]$user)

$w7="\\$pc\c$\users\$user\desktop"

if(Test-Path $w7){

    #Desktop:
    $colItems = (Get-ChildItem $w7 | Measure-Object -ErrorAction "SilentlyContinue" -property length -sum) 
    $msg = "$w7 -- " + "{0:N2}" -f ($colItems.sum / 1MB) + " MB"
    Write-host -ForegroundColor Green "$msg"

    #Files:
    Get-ChildItem -Recurse -force -Include *.* -exclude *.ini, *.lnk $w7 -ErrorAction "SilentlyContinue" | ls | Select-Object @{Name="Ficheros";Expression={$_.FullName}}, @{Name="Megas";Expression={$_.Length / 1MB}}


}

else{
    Write-Host -BackgroundColor White -ForegroundColor Red "FAIL"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this?

```
Name="Ficheros";Expression={$_.FullName -replace '.*?(\\Desktop.*)','$1'}
```

EDIT:
Updating  for non-greedy regex as suggested by @TheMadTechnician

Comment: I was just writing something very similar up. You want a non-greedy `.*?` though, otherwise if they have a subfolder named Desktop it won't parse correctly.